# How to use PRAGMA integrity_check for attached databases?

Tags: android, sqlite

I use an SQLITE database in my apps, but I sometimes need to attach another one temporarily in order to exchange data.

I first use:

```
ATTACH DATABASE db/path AS db
```

Then I use the following to check the integrity:

```
PRAGMA integrity_check
```

The problem is it seems to be checking only the main database, not the databases I attached temporarily.

Is there a way to check all the databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented in the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#syntax), you can put the database name before the pragma name:

```
PRAGMA db.integrity_check;
```